# Limit of measurable functions w.r.t. a chain of sigma algebras

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am studying Brownian motion, in particular Blumenthal's law, and it came to me the following question that I cannot answer myself.

Let $(\mathcal{F}_n)$ be a family of sigma algebras in a measurable space such that $\mathcal{F}_{n+1}\subset \mathcal{F}_n$ for every $n$ and $f_n$ be a sequence of functions with limit $f$ s.t. $f_n$ is $\mathcal{F}_n$ measurable. Is it true that $f$ is $\cap_n \mathcal{F}_n$ measurable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true.

To show that $f$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable where $\mathcal{F} := \bigcap \limits _{n=1}^{\infty} \mathcal{F}_n$, take any measurable set $B$ in the codomain and fix $n \in \mathbb{N}$. It suffices to show that $f^{-1}[B] \in \mathcal{F}_n$. Note that $f_n, f_{n+1}, f_{n+2}, \ldots$ is a sequence of $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable functions convergent to $f$, hence $f$ is also $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable. Therefore $f^{-1}[B] \in \mathcal{F}_n$, as required.